# Only one instance of a ScriptManager can be added to the page in asp.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, ajax, user-controls

When I'm trying to add user control I got this error

> Only one instance of a ScriptManager can be added to the page

Code:

.ascx

```
<%@ Control Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="VisaUserControl.ascx.cs" Inherits="Portal.VisaUserControl" %>
<%@ Register Assembly="BasicFrame.WebControls.BasicDatePicker" Namespace="BasicFrame.WebControls" TagPrefix="dp" %>
<asp:ScriptManager ID="scriptmanager1" runat="server"></asp:ScriptManager>
<div id="divreg" runat="server">
<table id="tbl" runat="server">
    <tr>
    <td>
        <asp:Label ID="lbl2" runat="server"></asp:Label>
    </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> Visa Number:</td>
<td><asp:TextBox ID="txtUser" Width="160px" runat="server"/></td>
<td> Country Name:</td>
<td><asp:DropDownList ID="dropCountry" Width="165px" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> Type of Visa:</td>
<td><asp:DropDownList ID="dropVisa" Width="165px" runat="server" OnSelectedIndexChanged="dropVisa_SelectedIndexChanged"></asp:DropDownList></td>
<td> Type of Entry:</td>
<td><asp:DropDownList ID="dropEntry" Width="165px" runat="server"></asp:DropDownList></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td> Expiry Date</td>
    <td><asp:TextBox ID="txtDate" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        <ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender ID="CalendarExtender1" runat="server" 
                          TargetControlID="txtDate" PopupButtonID="Imgbtnfromdate" Format="dd/MM/yyyy">
                      </ajaxToolkit:CalendarExtender>
    </td>
<td>
<asp:Button ID="btnRemove" Text="Remove" runat="server" OnClick="btnRemove_Click" />
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</div>
```

.aspx.cs

```
  protected override void LoadViewState(object savedState)
    {
        base.LoadViewState(savedState);

        GenerateControls();
    }



    private void GenerateControls()
    {
        foreach (string i in NoOfControls)
        {
            VisaUserControl ctrl = (VisaUserControl)Page.LoadControl("VisaUserControl.ascx");
            ctrl.ID = i;
            this.rpt1.Controls.Add(ctrl);
        }
    }
```

Here is the problem

```
    protected void btnAddVisa_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        List<string> temp = null;
        var uc = (VisaUserControl)this.LoadControl(@"VisaUserControl.ascx");

        string id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        uc.ID = id;

        temp = NoOfControls;
        temp.Add(id);
        NoOfControls = temp;
        rpt1.Controls.Add(uc);
    }
```

In the below image if I click the Add button, I get the error:

[image]

Comment: In User control page I have added only one script manager

Answer (score 29, accepted):

Try removing `ScriptManager` from user control.

You have definitely added a ScriptManager somewhere else in your `.aspx` Page or MasterPage. Check these pages.

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

In case you require `ScriptManager` on Master page,In this case, there is NO need to have a ScriptManager in userControl.  Follow below rules:

- Ensure you have one and only one `<asp:Scriptmanager>` on the masterpage.
- Ensure you also have one and only one `<asp:ScriptManagerProxy>` on each and every content page that might require a script manager

Below is what [**`MSDN`**](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398863.aspx) says about `ScriptManager` Control.

> Only one instance of the ScriptManager control can be added to the
>   page.   The page can include the control directly, or indirectly
>   inside a nested   component such as a user control, content page for a
>   master page, or nested  master page. If a page already contains a
>   ScriptManager control, but a nested   or parent component needs
>   additional features of the ScriptManager control,  the component can
>   include a ScriptManagerProxy control. For example, the ScriptManagerProxy control enables you to add scripts and services
>   that   are specific to nested components

Comment: In Master page I don't need script manager but some other page i have used script manager

Comment: So, Is the page in which you added your UserControl also contains ScriptManager ?? remove ScriptManager from userControl then

Comment: the master page. it seems to be added automatically when you create a new webforms project

Answer (score 1):

Are you using Script Manager on the Page where you are using this User Control? You will get an error if your Parent Page where you are using User Control already has Script Manager defined.

Best practice is to have the ScriptManager on the Master Page.

Remove the Script Manager from your User Control. It should work then.

Take a look at [AJAX ScriptManager in UserControl](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/650927/ajax-scriptmanager-in-usercontrol).

Answer (score 1):

it seems you are using scriptmanager on some place in your usercontrol.

try to remove it, only the reason of this error is scriptmanager can not be defined more thane one time in page

Answer (score -2):

If using a master page and AjaxControlToolkit doesn't work inside,then replace:

```
<asp:ScriptManager ID="smContent" runat="server">
</asp:ScriptManager>
```

With something like this:

```
<AjaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager ID="smContent" runat="server">
</AjaxToolkit:ToolkitScriptManager>
```

http://forums.asp.net/t/1923659.aspx?Using+ScriptManager+or+ToolkitScriptManager+with+ASP+NET+3+5+AJAX+Website