# Server Error in '/' Application. Only one instance of a ScriptManager can be added to the page

Tags: c#, asp.net

Server Error in '/' Application.
Only one instance of a ScriptManager can be added to the page.
Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace for more information about the error and where it originated in the code.

Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: Only one instance of a ScriptManager can be added to the page.

```
<td>
        <asp:ScriptManager ID="ScriptManager1" runat="server">
        </asp:ScriptManager>
</td>
```

I only have one instance of a script manager. Can you help me?

Comment: You are sure there is not a master page or usercontrol that brings its own scriptmanager? Do a file search and see if "scriptmanager" popups anywhere else in your solution. It most likely is a duplicate of this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19087044/only-one-instance-of-a-scriptmanager-can-be-added-to-the-page-in-asp-net/19087117 or else one of these might [help diagnose](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%22Only+one+instance+of+a+ScriptManager+can+be+added+to+the+page%22+is%3Aq&mixed=0).

Comment: You are right, one instance of script manager was at master page